# Build failed with an exception - noinspection LifecycleAnnotationProcessorWithJava8

Tags: android

When I built Android App. The error shows below

> Build file '/Users/tommychou/Downloads/1Rramp-Android-master/app/build.gradle' line: 95
>   A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
>   Could not get unknown property 'LifecycleAnnotationProcessorWithJava8' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Line 95 is

```
enter code here noinspection LifecycleAnnotationProcessorWithJava8
```